# I am not able to connect to my SQL Server. I am not sure why

Tags: sql-server

I am not able to connect to my SQL Server. I am not sure why... Also I am getting a message, but I am not able to understand it.

[image]

Comment: You either don’t have a default instance installed or the service isn’t running. If you click the server name drop down and browse do you see other local instances?

Comment: No, I don't see anything like that.

Comment: It is blank....

Comment: Start -> run "services.msc" - do you see a SQL Server service? Is it stopped?

Comment: Yes, I can see.. list of them

Answer (score 0):

Try connect to a specified SQLEXPRESS Instance; `DESKTOP-MIAVK8J\SQLEXPRESS`

I've never had any trouble connecting to that. Otherwise like commented, the instance is not running.